# Close dropdown by clicking outside

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't quite understand why my script does not working:

```
$(() => {
    let dropdown = $('.passengers-main-dropdown'),
        drop = dropdown.siblings('.dropdown-box');

    dropdown.on('click', function(){
        $(this).addClass('active');
        drop.addClass('active');
    });

    $(document).on('click', function(e){
        if(dropdown.is(e.target) || !drop.is(e.target) || drop.has(e.target).length === 0) {
            drop.removeClass('active');
            dropdown.removeClass('active');
        }
    });
});
```

The logic here is: when clicking on element with class `.passengers-main-dropdown` then dropdown becomes `.active`. And by clicking on document, algorithm checking for:

1. Dropdown not being a target of click
2. `.passengers-main-dropdown` is a target of click
3. Any dropdown's child elements are not a target of click

Am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: read about stopPropagation

Comment: @ iXplo `stopPropagation()` is a really bad idea because it can prevent another scripts work.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use `closest()`:

```
$(document).on('click', function(e){
    var $tgt = $(e.target);
    if($tgt.closest('.passengers-main-dropdown').length 
         || !$tgt.closest('.dropdown-box').length)  {
        drop.removeClass('active');
        dropdown.removeClass('active');
    }
});
```

Comment: Something wrong...can't be null. jQuery  always returns an array like object, even when no selector matches